# Some questions on probability spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I wanted to double check if my thoughts were correct and would appreciate any tips/help/other ways of going about it.

> 1. Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and let $\mathscr{F}=2^{\mathbb{R}^{2}}$. Is $\mathscr{F}$ a $\sigma$-field over $\Omega$?

Yes, $\mathbb{R}^{2} \in \mathscr{F}$ by definition of $\mathscr{F}$. Also, we can show it is closed under complements and under countable unions. Not part of the question, but would a probability space be possible using this $\Omega$ and $\mathscr{F}$?

> 2. Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $\mathscr{F}=2^{\Omega}$. Suppose that P is some probability measure on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$, specified in some way, but simply unknown to us. Consider the set $S=\{\frac{n}{100}: n = 1,2,3, ..., 100\}$. Is it the case that there necessarily exists a number $p \in S$ such that no event in $\mathscr{F}$ has probability equal to $p$?

I am leaning towards yes. The collection $\mathscr{F}$ has $2^{6}=64$ elements and the cardinality of the set $S$ is $100$. Each element in the collection $\mathscr{F}$ has a defined probability, because it is a possible outcome. So there should be $64$ distinct values of $P(E)$, $E$ being an element of the collection $\mathscr{F}$. But since $|S|$ > $|\mathscr{F}|$ it has to be that there exists a number $p \in S$ such that no event in $\mathscr{F}$ has probability equal to $p$.

> 3. Suppose $(\Omega, \mathscr{F}, P)$ is a probability space and that A and B are events in $\mathscr{F}$. Suppose further that $P(A)+P(B) \geq 1$. Must it be the case that either A or B occurs?

I am no too sure. Does "either A or B occurs" mean either A, or B, or both? How can the probability of two events be greater than 1? Unless you let $A=\Omega$ and $B$ be any other event with positive probability. But in that case, B is a proper subset of A so only A is really occurring? I am just very confused.

> 4. Suppose $\Omega=\{a,b\}$. Let $\mathscr{F}=2^{\Omega}$. Show that there exist probability measures $P'$ and $P$ on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$ s.t $P(\{a\})=0.1$ and $P(\{a\})=0.7$.

You can choose $P'$ to be the function that takes $\{a\}$ to $0.1$ and $\{b\}$ to $0.9$, and choose $P$ to be the function that takes $\{a\}$ to $0.7$ and $\{b\}$ to $0.3$. Then just show that these functions satisfy Kolmogorov's 3 axioms?

Comment: 1. Yes of course for example bivariate probability distributions as an example of a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: 2. Yes exactly, there are at most 64 distinct events in said sigma algebra but the set S has 100 distinct probabilities.

Comment: Is there a typo? Did you mean $P(\{a\})=0.1$ and $P'(\{a\})=0.7$? Yes your method of showing $P$ satisfies the 3 axioms seems valid

Comment: 3. Try drawing some venn diagrams for 3 events A, B, C. Let's say P(A)+P(B)=1 but there intersection has probability one third. P(A) = 2/3, P(B) = 1/3 i.e. $A \cap B = B$. Then you can still give C probability a third which I think you mentioned

Comment: 4. Yes exactly like Yip Jung said. Your example works, you are assigning zero probability to $A \cap B$ in both cases which is fine

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I am still a bit confused on 3. Can you expand on 3.? What is the set C and how did I mention it?

Comment: Haha i don't think you mentioned it actually. Three events A, B, C. B contained within A. Have probabilities of A and B add up to more than one. But in actual fact event C could happen too as A and B weren't independent